# How to recover my website page ranking, after using google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, meta-tags, google-ranking

My website was ranking in the fifth page when searching company name on google. But after i added key words with meta tag and google analytics code for better seo i lost my website name presence in entire google search results.Now google analytics showing i have more than page visitors than before. But bounce rate is 82%. If you can suggest me what i can do to bring my website name in search results , that would be a great help for me.

thanks,[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically your results can fluctuate after making SEO corrections to your site.  For example adding new keywords and title tags forces Google to redefine the content of your site. During this reindexing they will sometimes move your site around.  But after a few days it should bounce back. This is especially true if your site and business are new. Here are a few good resources on the topic written by [SEO Roundtable](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ranking-drop-fix-16354.html), [Quick Sprout](https://www.quicksprout.com/2014/02/12/why-your-search-rankings-are-dropping-and-7-ways-to-fix-it/) and [Myself](https://www.seomechanic.com/website-drop-google-ranking/).

Another good place to check is the Moz's [Google Algorithm History](https://moz.com/google-algorithm-change) page. This helps you determine if your fluctuation was due to something you did or possibly due to an Algo update.

Happy hunting!

Comment: Thank you for your reply SEO Mechanic. if i remove googleanalytic code from there, or i remove keywords, can i get the old ranking back? what should i do? could you please reply